# Exception and throwable not being caught

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs

I am running Selenium tests and I do not want the thread to end so I am catching everything I can. This is the structure of my program

My Main.java

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++)
{
    System.out.println("Inside loop to create threads!");
    System.out.println("Number of threads to create: " + numberOfThreads);
    totalNumberOfThreads++;
    String threadName = "Thread" + totalNumberOfThreads;
    if (type.contains("auto"))
    {
        newThread = new Thread(new Test());
    }

    UncaughtExceptionHandler handler = new UncaughtExceptionHandler()
    {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable ex)
        {
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try
            {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("throwable.txt"), true);
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos);
            ex.printStackTrace(ps);
        }
    };

    newThread.setName(threadName);
    newThread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(handler);
    newThread.start();
}
```

Test.java

```
public class Test extends Common implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        WebDriver driver = null;
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
                // bunch of test code
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (Throwable t)
            {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
                driver.quit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Even though I am catching Exceptions and Throwables in Test.java I still see the following exception in throwable.txt from time to time which means the error is not being catched in Test.java

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 02:56:46'
System info: host: 'localhost', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.1.5-x86_64-linode61', java.version: '1.8.0_60'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:589)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:618)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.quit(RemoteWebDriver.java:464)
    at myprogram.Test.run(Test.java:155)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The PhantomJS/GhostDriver server has unexpectedly died!
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 02:56:46'
System info: host: 'localhost', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.1.5-x86_64-linode61', java.version: '1.8.0_60'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSCommandExecutor.execute(PhantomJSCommandExecutor.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:568)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:30041 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:151)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:143)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:89)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:134)
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSCommandExecutor.execute(PhantomJSCommandExecutor.java:82)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:74)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134)
    ... 18 more
```

Comment: what do you have at line 155 of class test ? `myprogram.Test.run(Test.java:155)` ... isn't `driver.quit()` ?

Comment: driver.quit(); which is in the finally block. now I see what is going on. Thank you

Comment: Side note on code quality: test code is as important as production code; therefore it should be written with the same scrutiny as that one. In that sense: ever read "Clean code"  by Robert Martin?

Comment: @Jägermeister I will check his book thanks for recommendation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the stacktrace, you can see that the exception is thrown by the driver.quit(), in the finally. If you want to catch thoses, you have to surround the call to quit() by another try{}

```
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.quit(RemoteWebDriver.java:464)
at myprogram.Test.run(Test.java:155)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your finally is still not surrounded by the try/catch.

You need something like:

```
  finally{
      try{
        driver.quit();
      }catch(Exception ex){
        //do something
      }
  }
```